# Get HostControl from region in PRISM

Tags: c#, wpf, prism, prism-4

Is there anyway to get the hostcontrol / parentcontrol from a region in PRISM C# WPF. Im trying to write an custom region behaviour that modifies the hostcontrol if there is no views in the region.

There is a HostControl property in RegionBehavior class but it is alwasy null. How do i set it ? or how to get the hostcontrol.
Thanks for advice!

```
[Export(typeof(CollapseRegionBehavior))]
[PartCreationPolicy(CreationPolicy.NonShared)]
public class CollapseRegionBehavior : RegionBehavior, IHostAwareRegionBehavior
{

    public DependencyObject HostControl { get; set; }

    protected override void OnAttach()
    {
        if (this.Region.ActiveViews.Count() == 0)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you adding the RegionBehavior manually or do you register it in the bootstrapper in `ConfigureDefaultRegionBehaviors`?

It seems that if you add a behavior manually like this:

```
IRegion region = regionManager.Regions["MyRegion"];
region.Behaviors.Add("MyBehaviorKey", new MyBehavior());
```

the `IHostAwareRegionBehavior` interface has no effect. If you look at the PRISM source code in RegionBehaviorCollection.cs (Prism.Dektop.Regions) you'll clearly see that the Add method does not do anything related to the `IHostAwareRegionBehavior` interface.

However in RegionAdapterBase.cs, the interface is checked for in `AttachDefaultBehaviors`.

I ended up registering my RegionBehavior in the bootstrapper and checking the region name to see if there is work to be performed. Not very clean, but it works.

Comment: Yes i noticed that too. It seems that IHostAwareRegionBehavior only works when in bootstrapper after that stage it cannot find the HostControl. Thanks!